# System.Net.HttpListener only explicitly implements IDisposable

Tags: .net

Why does HttpListener explicitly implement IDisposable.  This means you have to cast to IDisposable before calling dispose and in my opinion makes the fact you have to call dispose less obvious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. You don't need an explicit cast if you use a [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) block. (This is the preferred idiom, where possible, for dealing with `IDisposable` objects.)

   ```
   using (HttpListener hl = /* ... */)
   {
       // ...
   }
   ```
2. It has a [`Close`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.close.aspx) method which is pretty-much an alias for [`Dispose`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355979.aspx). (Not my favourite pattern, but the framework designers seem to like it!)

   ```
   HttpListener hl = /* ... */
   try
   {
       // ...
   }
   finally
   {
       hl.Close();
   }
   ```

Comment: Maybe the using thing is why they have explicitly implemented the IDisposable interface.  I'm utilizing the asynchronous methods though so it is difficult to go the using route.